Pop-up extent out of screen and wrong title of the pop-ups
I am generating a map in the latest version of qgis2web using openlayers but having several overlapping layers the pop up goes out of scale, from the visual of the web, as shown in the image.

It has a scroll bar but when I want to use it as I move the mouse the pop up closes and also I would like not to depend on the scroll bar to be able to see all the content of the pop up. I tried modifying max-height in qgis2web.css file but the problem persists. I'm not sure if I'm modifying the code in the right place or which file/line I should modify.
`#popup-content>table {
font-size: 11.4px; 

}
th, td {
vertical-align: top; 

text-align: left; 

color: #333; 

}
th {
min-width: 300px; 

}
td {
min-width: 300px; 

/* max-height: 70vw; 

max-width: 70vw; */ 

}
td img {
max-height: 40vw!important; 

max-width: 40vw!important; 

} `
I also want to delete the word layer from the pop up title, as it is shown in the image. I want only the name of the layer to appear as the title of the pop up like for example: Nacional_Riego, only. I don't know if I should change it in the file qgis2web.js, qgis2web.css or layers.js


Please upload your project to the web and link it

Here I leave the link to the whole folder: https://ubauba-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/fbrestelli_uba_ar/Ep5klhRU0M9NjGp-M53a6twBRWpw7cb9TgZ2_S5NwKXGZg?e=oTIRjB

Good morning,
first of all I advise you to disable the "popup on hover". This method is intended for popups with little data that do not need to be scrolled.
Then I advise you, given the large amount of information present in the popup, to reduce it considerably.
Write this code at the bottom of your qgis2web.css file
    #popup-content {
    max-height: 15vw !important;
    }
    th, td {
    min-width: 200px;
    }

To delete the word Layer: from the popup edit the qgis2web.js file, find this line and remove the part I highlight. Be careful, you will have to do it in 4 identical lines.

ATTENTION:
The changes I suggested you can apply after export, for each single project you export, or you can modify the qgis2web base code so that every time you export you will have these changes. Be careful though, if you update qgis2web you will lose your changes.
To modify the base code, reach qgis2web.css and qgis2web.js in your QGIS plugin installation path for windows:
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qgis2web\openlayers


Thank You very much @andreaordonselli!!!!

Not at all :) Please consider donating a virtual coffee via the qgis2web github home page to support development.
